# Undefined variable $no_antrian

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a queuing system in Laravel but I have problems with coding and don't understand how to set up the coding correctly. Can anyone help me?

```
public function store(Request $request ){

        $latestAntrian = Antrian::where('layanan', $this->layanan)
            ->where('tanggal_antrian', now()->toDateString())
            ->latest('id_antrian')
            ->first();

         if (!$latestAntrian) {
            if($this->layanan === 'anak'){
                $this->no_antrian = 'A1';
            } elseif ($this->layanan === 'ibu'){
                $this->no_antrian = 'B1';
            } elseif ($this->layanan === 'lansia'){
                $this->no_antrian = 'C1';
            }
            $this->tanggal_antrian = now()->toDateString();
        } else {

            $kode_awal = substr($latestAntrian->no_antrian, 0, 1);
            $angka = (int) substr($latestAntrian->no_antrian, 1);
            $angka +=1;
            $no_antrian = $kode_awal . $angka;
            $tanggal_antrian = $latestAntrian->tanggal_antrian;
        }

        $data                   = new Antrian;
        $data->no_antrian       = ($no_antrian);
        $data->nama             = $request->get('nama');
        $data->no_hp            = $request->get('no_hp');
        $data->layanan          = $request->get('layanan');
        $data->tanggal_antrian  = ($tanggal_antrian);
        $data->save();
   
         Alert::success('Data Berhasil Ditambah');
 
         return redirect()->route('antrianuser')->with([
             'success' => 'Data Berhasil Di Tambah'
         ]);
    }
```

help me by improving this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL:TR; You are facing `Undefined variable $no_antrian` because that variable is assigned only in `else` branch of your condition.

---

Some issues with your current code:

1. The `$tanggal_antrian` (`$queue_date`) variable is assigned only in `else` branch, in other you assign `$this->$tanggal_antrian` and that's why you face `undefined variable` error in `$data->tanggal_antrian  = ($tanggal_antrian);` line. I assume you intended to assign local variable in both cases.
2. Not sure what you wanted to achieve by adding brackets in the `$data->tanggal_antrian = ($tanggal_antrian);` line. Whatever was the reason, these brackets are pointless here.
3. No error handling, which is bad idea -> what happens if the save operation fails?
4. Finally, code isn't DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself); there are repetitive blocks that can be refactored.

I'd also suggest you work on your coding style:

1. You mix naming conventions (`snake_case` vs `camelCase`). Stick to one.
2. I recommend you resist from using non-English to name your variables/methods as this, combined with the fact there's no PHPDoc blocks makes the code hard to follow.

So I'd tidy the code more/less like this (I replaced all non-English names with the translations, with the exception for `Antrian` model class, which you should rename to `Queue` or so too):

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Get the latest queue entry based on the service and current date
    $latest_queue = Antrian::where('service', $request->service)
                          ->where('queue_date', now()->toDateString())
                          ->latest('queue_id')
                          ->first();

    $queue_number = '';
    $queue_date = now()->toDateString();

    // Generate new queue number based on the latest entry and type of service
    if (!$latest_queue) {
        $prefixes = ['child'   => 'A',
                     'mother'  => 'B',
                     'elderly' => 'C'];
        $queue_number = isset($prefixes[$request->service])
            ? $prefixes[$request->service] . '1'
            : 'Z1';
    } else {
        $initial_code = substr($latest_queue->queue_number, 0, 1);
        $number = (int)substr($latest_queue->queue_number, 1);
        $number++;
        $queue_number = "{$initial_code}{$number}";
    }

    // Create and save new Queue entry
    $data = new Antrian([
        'queue_number'  => $queue_number,
        'name'          => $request->name,
        'mobile_number' => $request->mobile_number,
        'service'       => $request->service,
        'queue_date'    => $queue_date,
    ]);

    $redirect_data = $data->save()
        ? ['success' => 'Data Successfully Added']
        : ['error' => 'Data Failed to Add'];
    return redirect()->route('queueUser')->with($redirect_data);
}
```

Not sure what PHP version you use but if 8, I'd replace

```php
$queue_number = isset($prefixes[$request->service])
    ? $prefixes[$request->service] . '1'
    : 'Z1';
```

with shoter form:

```php
$queue_number = ($prefixes[$request->service] ?? 'Z') . '1';
```

Comment: Thank you master, it really helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are defining $this->no_antrian in a class property and in the else block in variable.
When you assign :

```
$data->no_antrian = ($no_antrian);
```

You are using only variable so it could be undefined.

try to change in the else block :

```
$no_antrian = $kode_awal . $angka;
```

by :

```
$this->no_antrian = $kode_awal . $angka;
```

and :

```
$data->no_antrian       = ($no_antrian);
```

by :

```
$data->no_antrian       = $this->no_antrian;
```

Comment: The answer makes no sense

Comment: First contribution...

Comment: I tried earlier but the data couldn't be read